# Xml button field value is always null

Tags: java, android, xml, button, fragment

I searched many threads but couldn't understand the problem in my code. I am trying to add `setOnClickListener` functionality on a button from a fragment. It gives me

> nullpointer exception at allNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener().

Upon debugging I understand that the variable `allNews` is null.

Below is my layout code.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <Button
            android:id = "@+id/b_all"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="All \n news"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:textAllCaps="false"


            />
```

And here is my java code:

```
public class CategoriesFragment extends Fragment {

    public Button allNews;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_menu, container, false);
        getActivity().setTitle("Play");

        allNews = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_all);

        return rootView;
    }

    public void onViewCreated(View view, @android.support.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        allNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Newsmain.class));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

I am unable to understand what am I missing. There is a `scrollview` inside the same xml. Should we handle such layouts/fields seperately ?

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Satya

SOLVED: I renamed the xml with activity_news_category and then the variable is not null anymore. Prev the xml was named as activity_news_menu. Thnx for all who attempted to help.

Comment: Are you sure, you are inflating the correct xml layout file for fragment?

Comment: I wanted that xml layout for that fragment. Do I need to include anything else in either files for the connection other than                                                 
                                                                                                             View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_menu, container, false);  ?

Comment: Your code seems fine. I'm just trying to make sure that "activity_news_menu.xml" is actually having a button with id "@+id/b_all"

Comment: yes it has. I just posted the complete xml.

Comment: This seems to be fine to me. The only possibility I can think of you are inflating the wrong xml, causing findViewById not able to find the button with "@+id/b_all". Upon debugging, you found allNews null inside onCreateView?

Comment: yes. allNews is null inside onCreateView. Pls note rootView is not null though.                                                                                                 
 Even if I keep allNews =
 (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b_all) inside onViewCreated, allNews value is still null. But as you see, the button with @+id/b_all is present in the xml.

Comment: If you getting allNews after this line "allNews = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_all);" as null that simply means that there is no view with id b_all.

Comment: For testing can you create a new xml file and pass it to this fragment with new button and different Id.

Comment: please give answer and mark it answered so people will refrain from giving solutions..

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onViewCreated(View view, @android.support.annotation.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

allNews = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.b_all);
        allNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {

                    startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Newsmain.class));

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

UPDATE:
instead of `rootView` it should be `view`

Add `allNews = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_all);` in `onViewCreated()` and remove it from `onCreateView()`

Comment: Thank you...still same problem. variable allNews is null and thus nullpointerException

Comment: yes...with rootView it gives error.                                                         
 allNews = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.b_all);

Answer (score 0):

public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

```
      View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_news_menu, container, false);
    getActivity().setTitle("Play");

    allNews = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.b_all);
```

allNews.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {

                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Newsmain.class));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Use set onclicklistener in OncreateView method.Hope this helps

Comment: Tq...I tried this also but it gave the same nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

1) Close the `LinearLayout` properly.

2) Remove the space between the    `android:id = "@+id/b_all"`, so you have:

```
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b_all"
                android:layout_width="70dp"
                android:layout_height="70dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="All \n news"
                android:textColor="#FFF"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:background="@drawable/button_bg_round"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then rebuild the project.

Comment: R.layout.activity_news_menu .... ensure that this is the actual layout file name....this file name suggests you are inflating a menu and not normal Activity XML

Comment: Thank you so much. I renamed the xml with activity_news_category and then it went through

Comment: I am glad it helped. Happy coding :)